# Why will this easy VBA code not work

Tags: vba, excel

Can any one see why this isn't working for me?

My cell H6 contains a 12 digit number, thus the use of Long.
Any thoughts on how to adjust this code in order for it to work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'This line stops the worksheet updating on every change, it only updates when cell'H6 or H7 is touched  
If Intersect(Target, Range("H6:H7")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'Set the Variables to be used  
Dim pt As PivotTable  
Dim Field As PivotField  
Dim NewCat As Long  

'Here you amend to suit your data  
Set pt = Worksheets("Data1").PivotTables("PivotTable10")    
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("[Produkter].[EAN].[EanID]")  

NewCat = Worksheets("Data1").Range("H6").Value    

'This updates and refreshes the PIVOT table

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTabel10").PivotFields("[Produkter].[EAN].[EanID]")  
    .ClearAllFilters
    .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=ActiveSheet.Range("H6").Value
End With
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? What is it doing now? Do you get an error message? Have you [taken the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Comment: Try to describe better what is happening in your code, what you are trying to acheive, and if you are getting an error at what line. The post in current state can't tell us much and it's almost impossible to help you

Comment: Sorry. 
I would like to be able to enter a 12-digit number in cell H6 so that the filter in the pivot table will change to that number. I get a little different errors but the most common are: run-time error 6 overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Long is only 32 bits so you can only store 9 decimal digits. Use Double or (only if you have a 64bit-version) LongLong.

Comment: Hmm if i use Double i get: User defined type not defined.
And if i use LongLong i get: Unable to get the PivotTabels property of the worksheet class. But if have checked and it should be right.